# How Do I Fetch Console Buffer History After a Clear-Host?

Tags: powershell, console, powershell-ise, input-history

If I'm using the PowerShell ISE and I have a bunch of text on the screen from the previous commands I've run, I could then issue a 'Clear-Host' command to clean it up.  The cursor goes to the top line of the screen, prints the prompt, and then waits again.

But once I do that I can't scroll up to see previous output anymore.  Is that previous output saved anywhere?  How can I look at the output of commands I've run before I did Clear-Host?

I have a script that does a Clear-Host, but I didn't actually intend to lose that old screen buffer history when I ran the script, so I'm hoping I can get it back somehow.  I don't find it in the output of '$host |Export-Clixml file.xml', which was my first thought.

Comment: There is no variable that contains the contents of the current display, if you clear it its gone. And as far as i know there isnt any console history feature in ISE either. You could look if there is an add-on for ISE that does it but at least on microsofts page there isnt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That feature is missing from Powershell ISE, at least up to, and including, version 3.0.
Even Start-Transcript and Stop-Transcript will throw "This host does not support transcription."

However, it looks like someone came up with a "Transcript" module to address this [over here.](http://www.powertheshell.com/transcript/)

Hopefully that will provide what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you, Booga.  Add-ons are a pain to manage, for my situation, but I appreciate the pointer and I'll give it a try.